# FInding length of list : 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm trying to solve a simple Hackerrank problem using python but stuck in a strange error. The code seems to be working in IDLE. I'm using python 3.4

Have a look at this code

```
lines = int(input())
n = lines
strings = []
while n>0:
    strings.append(input())
    n -=1
len = []
n=lines
while n>0:
    strl = list(strings[lines-n])
    result = []

    print(len(strl)) -----> throws error list not callable 
    n-=1
```

Comment: so basically I'm trying to find length of a string after I've converted it into a list inside the while loop. I intend to store the length of the string as in print(len(strl)) changes to len.append(len(strl))

Comment: got the answer, please IGNORE the question

Comment: Grijesh, thanks for your input. I added the comment so that people dont waste time on something that is already solved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rename `len = []`.

It's linked to using `len` for both the function `len()` and your variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
len = []
# ^ here's your problem
```

You created a new `len` variable that hides the built-in `len`. When you try to call `len` later in your code, it tries to use a list as a function and fails. Call it something else.